# Custom MenuStrip in Visual C# Express

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ribbon

I would like to create very nice looking menu as shown on the picture:

[image: Menu]

How can I do this? I can create one item with image and text behind it, but how to group them etc.

Comment: That type of look is called Ribbon. See this question: [The Best Ribbon Interface Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206370/the-best-ribbon-interface-library)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Winforms, this ribbon interface is very nice to use with a well documented intuitive API

Check out Krypton from Component Factory:
https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton